# Cythonize but not compile .pyx files using setup.py

Tags: python, cython, setuptools, setup.py, software-distribution

I have a Cython project containing several **.pyx** files. To distribute my project I would like to provide my generated **.c** files as recommended [in the Cython documentation](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html), to minimize problems with different Cython versions.

My current work flow is to build the project using:

```
me@machine$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

This cythonizes (i.e. translate **.pyx** files to **.c** / **.cpp** files using Cython) all **.pyx** files and then compiles them.
For a release I do not need the compiled (**.so**) files, so I basically ignore them. The problem is, I waste a lot of time with the useless compilation.

Is there a way to cythonize all **.pyx** files in the folder using the `setup.py`, without compiling them?

#### Edit: Why not just use `$ cython my_file.pyx`

I have about 20 **.pyx** files which have different [compiler directives](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html#compiler-directives). Calling `cython` on the command line for each file would be slower than just waiting for it to compile.

On the other hand creating a shell script to cythonize them would leave me with a second list of compiler directives that needs to be kept up to date. I would rather not do this, in order to keep my possible points of failure minimal.

Comment: Isn't `cython your_file.pyx` threre exactly for this reason!?

Comment: True, and I could write a shell script to apply it to all my `.pyx` files. But this would add another file to my project, that I would have to keep up to date, especially concerning the Cython arguments. Given that setuptools performs this task every time I build my project I hoped there could be a way to use this. Maybe I am just missed the right command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to create the C files without compiling them is first remove in setup.py "setup(...)" line and replace it with only the "cythonize("*.pyx")" part. Then run:

```
me@machine$ python setup.py
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i was looking for. In order to better integrate it with my existing setup file, I can check for a parameter like `--cythonize-only` that will only calll the cythonize part and run the whole setup part otherwise.